# PHP Script to fetch MySQL data not working

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a PHP script to fetch data off a MySQL database and check if the entered password matches with the one in the database. If yes, it should redirect the user to a site. However, when I run it, it will show the message defined as $errorMessage.

What am I doing wrong? The script is for a login form using bootstrap.

Thanks in advance!

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password") or die("Verbindung zum Server nicht möglich. Bitte kontaktiere uns.");
mysqli_select_db($link,"berufs_schule");

if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
$errorMessage = "Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten.";
$email=$_POST['email'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

if ($errorMessage != "" ) {
echo "<p class='message'>" .$errorMessage. "</p>";
}
else{
$query = "SELECT email, password FROM members WHERE email='$email'";

while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($query)):

        $name_db = $rows['name'];
        $password_db = $rows['password'];

        if(md5($password) == $password_db){

            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content=\"0; url=success.html\">";

        } else {

            echo "<p class='message'>Passwort falsch, bitte versuche es erneut!</p>";

        }
        endwhile;
}
}
?>
```

EDIT:
I removed the check for errorMessage now, and now it just shows me a blank screen and doesn't output that the password isn't correct ("Passwort falsch, bitte versuche es erneut!") or redirect me to the success.html. What can the error be?

EDIT 2: Test the script at http://test.enderpixel.net/berufs.schule/login.html

Comment: What kind of errorMessage do you get ? Please edit your question with the error

Comment: Since you first set `$errorMessage = "Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten.";` then the actual query will never be executed. This part `if ($errorMessage != "" ) { //... } else { /... }` will skip executing the query if `$errorMessage` is set.

Comment: Ah i see what the problem is. Your $errorMessage is defined so it is never empty

Comment: Totally correct what your script is doing. You define the `$errorMessage`, and then check if it is not equal to an empty string (which evaluates to true), so the query is never executed.

Comment: I removed the check for errorMessage now, and now it just shows me a blank screen and doesn't output that the password isn't correct ("Passwort falsch, bitte versuche es erneut!") or redirect me to the success.html. What can the error be?

Comment: What about to start debugging yourself instead of asking here after each step? If you want to develop applications, you have to be able to do such elementary actions yourself. Best case, use the debugger, worst case, use functions like `var_dump` and print debugging messages to find out what's happening.

Comment: BTW why is it possible to have more members with the same e-mail and potentially different passwords? How is it supposed to work? The member can have more accounts with the same e-mail and different password and he selects particular account by using the corresponding password? It seems to be a bit weird design to me.

Comment: @DawidFerenczy The script fetches the password from the MySQL database using the Email that is entered in the field on the login page, and check if the password that is entered in the form equals with the password in the database, so I don't really understand what you mean? And how can I debug? Chrome doesn't show any errors in console.

Comment: Well, it's not easy to help you because it's obvious you have no clue what you're doing. Why do you have such construct with the `while` loop, when you can do the database query with both *email* and *password* and you are done? Your code is badly indented so it's very hard to read. It's not a good idea to use MD5 (quite some years already). You're not checking if the query was successful at all (very bad)! `mysql_fetch_array` is not returning rows, but fields of a single row. Etc. I don't know where to start. I suggest you to start with learning.

Comment: I'm not really bad at PHP normally, but I do that MySQL thing for the first time. I apologize for my errors and I will do a little more research on this.

Answer (score 1):

Your code had multiple errors in it (errorMessage declaration, syntax error, open to SQL-injection), so take a look at this, you might find it helpful.

```
<?php
$errorMessage = "Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten.";

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Verbindung zum Server nicht möglich. Bitte kontaktiere uns.");
mysqli_select_db($link,"trainingcentre");

if (isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {

    // If either email or password is missing, show error emssage

    if (empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {

        echo $errorMessage;

    } else {

        // Lets escape user input
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

        $sql = "SELECT email, password FROM members WHERE email='$email'";

        $query = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

        // If query was successfull
        if ($query) {

            while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

                $password_db = $rows['password'];

                if (md5($password) == $password_db) {

                    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content=\"0; url=success.html\">";

                } else {

                    echo "<p class='message'>Passwort falsch, bitte versuche es erneut!</p>";

                }
            }

        } else { // If query failed, show error message

            echo $errorMessage;

        }

}
```

Don't copy-paste (I didn't test it), just look through.

Comment: I've just modified my code and fixed the errors you pointed out and it still doesn't work. It doesn't show the $errorMessage, just a blank screen again. If you'd like to test it yourself, go to http://test.enderpixel.net/berufs.schule/login.html